# rails slice- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I do the following in the console:

```
 1.9.3p194 :062 > @user = [name: "Joe", age: "17"]
 => [{:name=>"Joe", :age=>"17"}] 

 1.9.3p194 :063 > @user.slice(:name)
 TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

Why isn't slice returning [name: "Joe"]?

Answer (score 1):

You're embedding the hash in an array!

Try like this :

```
@user = {name: "Joe", age: "17"}
@user.slice(:name)
```

To get an array of only name and id on `User.all` :

```
array = User.all.map { |u| u.attributes.slice(:name, :id) }
```

`map` executes what you provide in the code block on each element `u` and builds an array with it, that is returned and put in the variable `array` in the above example.

`u.attributes` gives a Hash containing all attributes of the User model for an instance of User ... everything's that's saved in the DB.

Comment: Hmmm.  So how am I supposed to so something like:  @user= User.all and then get an array of just say the :name and :user_id?

Comment: Hmmm why would you want to do that? I'll add it to the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information provided, I'm not sure why you would want the overhead of array operations. Consider using OStruct instead.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html

The example you provided would look like this in OStruct:

```
require 'ostruct'
@user = OpenStruct.new
@user.name    = "John Smith"
@user.age     = 17

puts @user.name     # -> "Joe"
puts @user.age     # -> 17
```

No slicing and clean, fast-executing Ruby code.